# The question about espacing point, in the ODE theory.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\{x_n \}\subset \mathbb R$ be a increasing sequence coneverging to $b$, and let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb {R^n}$ be a  bounded (and maybe continuous) function defined on the open interval $(a, b)$. Let $|f(x)|\leqq M.$

And suppese $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=B\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b-0}f(x) \neq B$

---

The following is described in my textbook of ordinary differential equations, but I'm wondering the last point is true.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b-0}f(x) \neq B$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t. there is $x_0$ that satisfies $\|f(x_0)-B \| \geqq \epsilon$ and $b-\delta < x_0 < b$ for all $\delta>0$.

Next, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=b$, there exists $N_1$ s.t. $n\geqq N_1 \Rightarrow |x_n-b|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}$, i.e., $b-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}<x_n <b$, and since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=B$, there exists $N_2$ s.t. $n\geqq N_2 \Rightarrow \|f(x_n)-B\| <\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Then, letting $N=\max\{N_1, N_2\},$ $n\geqq N\Rightarrow b-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}<x_n <b, \ \|f(x_n)-B\| <\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$, and thus $b-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}<x_N <b, \ \|f(x_N)-B\| <\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Then, let $x_N ' $ satisfy
\begin{align}
&・ x_N < x_N' <b \\
&・ \|f(x)-B\|<\epsilon \ \ \mathrm {for} \ \ x_N\leqq x < x_N ' \\
&・ \|f(x_N ')-B\|= \epsilon.
\end{align}
($x_N'$ can be described as the point that $\|f(x)-B\|$ escapes from $\epsilon.$)

But I'm wondering whether such $x_N'$ exists. What guarantees the existence of $x_N'$ ?

Comment: As far as I can see this requires continuity of $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In my textbook, the continuity of $f$ is not mentioned, but maybe $f$ is continuous because in ODE theory, the functions we  consider  are usually continuous.

Comment: This appears to be a part of a theorem about the maximal domain of an ODE solution, that if the solution does not directly diverge to infinity at $b$, then it has to be oscillating and not differentiable in $b$. Thus no continuation is possible. In that context, $f$ is continuously differentiable for $a<x<b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Assuming that $f$ is continuous define $x_N'$ as $\inf \{x \in (X_N,b): \|f(x)-B\| \geq \epsilon\}$. You can verify that $X_N'$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I'm trying to prove…